# Personal Data Recovery on my Computer

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

I was previously using Windows 8.1 I had two partitions. My OS was located on the C:/ (primary) drive, and all my personal data was located on the D:/ (secondary) drive. I have now installed Ubuntu 14.04, and I am not able to find the D Drive or my data.

Is it possible to restore my data by any means? Please help!

Regards,

Deepak

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/740424/edit) your question to include the steps you took to install Ubuntu. Along with the output of `df -T` in a terminal - which will show what partitions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to find out what partitions you have on your computer now: From a command line, type `sudo fdisk -l` which should yield a list, hopefully along the lines of /dev/sda1, AND /dev/sda2 or similar.

If it does have both, then your data is safe in /dev/sda2 & you just need to get it to show up somewhere useful.
Try `mkdir tmp ; sudo mount /dev/sda2 tmp` (you may need to substitute sda2 with something else, depending on step 1 above's results); check out the contents of your new `tmp` directory.

If it doesn't, ie you only see the one partition, then the partition has been marked deleted - but probably not damaged yet.
In this case, STOP using it, reboot from the installation CD or USB, and grab a large removable drive with space to put your files. Make sure you connect to internet, and download a retrieval utility (I would recommend `foremost` - `sudo apt-get install foremost` which will hunt through the ENTIRE drive & copy *anything* it recognises & save it to the external drive - but without the original names... a big job for you. Next time, keep a backup!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely erased your disk before you installed.

If this is the case, I would suggest one of a number of data recovery tools. If you have the ability to create a live USB or CD, you can use one of the tools listed [HERE.](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/5-best-data-recovery-tools-for-linux-to-recover-data-or-deleted-partitions)

These should be able to recover your data, provided you haven't overwritten it during or after the installation. There really is never a 100% guarantee when it comes to data recovery (unless you work for the NSA), but these are definitely worth a try.